# New admin account cant access plugins.php

Tags: plugins, privileges

I am trying to add a plugin to a client's site. I can see everything in the dashboard except the plugin page and users pages.  I can install a plugin and see my own profile but cant see other installed plugins or other user profiles in the dashboard.  If i access the pages via direct link,  i get an insufficient privileges to access this page error. Any idea?

As requested... The values of my account in phpmyadmin:

wp_capabilities = a:1:{s:13:"administrator" s:1:"1" }
wp_user_level = 10
user_status = 0

Comment: FTP into the server and check the plugins directory. It sounds like there may be another plugin that has edited the user roles. It is also possible there is code in the functions.php file that is altering your permissions.

Comment: Yea problem is i dont know what code to look for.  Directory is 755. No idea what plugin would be interfering with user roles.

Comment: There are a ton of them that could, why not list them here for review. I would look for any functions related to user roles. Find them and post them here for review.

Comment: Also, when you go to your profile it says that you are an administrator? If it says Editor it is working as expected.

Comment: Profile says admin color scheme but nothing else that specifically says administrator or editor.

Comment: Then you aren't an admin. The color admin just changes the colors that you see when logging it. You have to contact the owner and have them change your role. if he says you are then see my earlier comments about plugins and the functions.php file.

Comment: Via the file manager i see: addfunc-header-footer-code, advanced-custom-fields-pro, advanced file manager 5, apobit wp ame pro, blogger 301 redirect, broken link checker, complete central backup, gold cart plugin, google analytics for wordpress, google author information in search results wordpress plugin, google sitemap generator, gravity forms constant contact, gravity forms, gravityformsauthorizenet, link patrol, pc-robotstxt, redirection, sar-friendly-smtp, ultimate google analytics, w3 total cache, wooslider220, wordpress https,  wordpress importer,  wordpress seo premium

Comment: None of those would mess with it. My guess is that you are not actually an admin. Contact the owner.

Comment: Wp db backup, wp e commerce, wp external links, wp internal links, wp robots txt, wpec linkpointe4sm-curl,  wpseo local

Comment: I have access to phpmyadmin and i created a new admin account via sql.  Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: That is info you should have added to your question. Edit the question with the values of each of the columns in the DB.

Comment: See my new update.

Comment: Are you using mutlisite?

Comment: Nope, single site as far as i am aware of.  I've seen so many posts about  multi sites having the same problem i am having. I just dont know whats causing it and i have managed wordpress sites before.

Answer (score 1):

if the account you are using is the administrator and not the editor go to wp-config.php file and change define('WP_DEBUG', false); to define('WP_DEBUG', true);.but if you are not the administrator this won't work.

Comment: How can one go to `wp-config.php`?

Comment: go to the directory where your website is installed. in the c panel public_html/ folder you will find it there.